# HasMap inserting null values instead of string?

Tags: java, excel, hashmap

Below is my code which I am trying to read the excel data using Apache POI and want to store the first column and last column values in Hashmap by taking First column values as keys and last column as values. I am facing an issue while putting the values in the hashmap. My expected output should be like

```
Key         value
UserDefined Xpath_original  
seldriver   xpath;//div[@id='mBody']    
Selenium    xpath;//table[@id='choice']/tbody/tr/td[1]/ul/li[1]
```

but I am getting the output as

*

```
null null
null
null xpath;//div[@id='mBody']
```

*
Below is my piece of code

```
package com.selenium.common;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

public class ReadMacroExcel {
public static void main(String[] args) {
 try {

         File f=new File("C:\\Users\\Rajaram.8.Kannuri\\Downloads\\Fire-IEBrowser1.4.xlsm");
         HashMap <String,String> innerMap =null;
         Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(f);
         System.out.println(workbook);
         int numberOfSheets = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
         org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet sheet=null; 
         String key = "";
         String value = "";
         //Get the  sheet in the xlsx file
         for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSheets; i++) {                         
             sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
             System.out.println(sheet.getSheetName());
             int firstColumn = sheet.getRow(0).getFirstCellNum();
             int lastColumn = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum(); 
             Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
             innerMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
             while(rowIterator.hasNext())
             {
                     Row row = rowIterator.next();

                     Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                     while (cellIterator.hasNext())
                     {

                         Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                         if(cell.getColumnIndex()==firstColumn||cell.getColumnIndex()==lastColumn-1)
                         {

                             switch (cell.getCellType())
                             {
                                 case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING: 
                                         key = cell.getStringCellValue();
                                         /*System.out.print(key + "\t");*/
                                        /* Thread.sleep(5000);*/
                                 break;
                                 case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                                        value = cell.getRichStringCellValue().toString();
                                        /*System.out.print(value + "\t");*/
                                        /*Thread.sleep(5000);*/
                                 break; 
                              }
                            System.out.print(innerMap.put(key,value));
                         }

                     }

                     System.out.println("");

                 }
           /*  System.out.println(innerMap.get("UserDefined"));*/
             }

     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }


    }
}
```

Can any one help me in solving this issue??

Comment: Sure. Add more print statements to your code to understand what it is doing. Or learn to use a debugger. If you don't know what your code is doing ... add means to allow you observing what it is doing. You dont need other people for that.

Comment: "`System.out.print(innerMap.put(key,value));`" This prints [the *old* value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put(K,%20V)). If there's nothing already in the map for that key, it will print `null`.

Comment: @GhostCat The problem is it is inserting null values I don't know whats happening there and that to I am new to java

Comment: Side note: `catch (Exception e)` is too broad; catch specific checked exceptions. Also, you didn't handle the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to print the inserted value with

```
System.out.print(innerMap.put(key,value));
```

However, `put` returns the **previous value** associated with the given key, or `null` if there was no mapping for that key.

See also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put-K-V-

You should use something like

```
innerMap.put(key,value);               // add the new mapping to the hashmap
System.out.print(innerMap);            // dumps the complete map with all entries
System.out.print(innerMap.get(key));   // dumps the value for the recently inserted key
```

Comment: Festar thank you for your answer but here the key and values are not null but dont know why it is putting null values

Comment: Because the first time you insert something, the previous value is null (since there was no entry for the given key before)